# Problems in installing vim-latex

Tags: vim-latex

I try to install [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download), a plugin for vim to edit latex file,
According to the download page

> > In step 3 of 4 :To install the included latex-suite.txt and latexhelp.txt files as vim help files, start vim and do the following:

```
helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

It promts

```
E150: Not a directory: ~/.vim/doc
```

Then I did

```
helptags ~/.vim/vim-latex-1.9.0/doc
```

nothing happened

> > Step 4 of 4: Done!
> >     Thats it! You are done! Now start editing a latex file in vim. Latex-Suite should start up automatically. You can do

```
:help latex-suite.txt
```

I got another error

```
E149: Sorry, no help for latex-suite.txt
```

I summarized the steps I did before

> > Step 1 of 4: Download and extract the archives

```
tar xvzf vim-latex-1.9.0.tar.gz -C ~/.vim
```

nothing wrong, there is one more file  `vim-latex-1.9.0.tar` under  `~/.vim`

> > Step 2 of 4: Set a few things in `.vimrc`

I copied the contents to my `.vimrc` file in a right way. 
there is no file named `tex.vim` under `~/.vim/ftplugin/` so I created one and copy the contents to my `tex.vim`

when I start editing `.tex` file, nothing paticular happened, so I guess I didn'd have  `vim-latex` installed. I don't know where I did wrong?

Comment: I took a quick look at the archive. Inside of it, there is another folder (`vim-latex-1.9.0`). This folder contains (among others) the folders `ftplugin` and `docs`. So it seems, that you have to copy the contents of this folder into your `~/.vim` folder (BUT I DIDN'T TEST IT). Also inside of the folder there is a `Makefile`. You could try `make install` which should install the plugin in `/usr/local` (system wide).

Comment: @Skillmon, I have tried as you suggested, it did work, thank you. Could you please tell me why `ftplugin` and `docs` must be placed under `vim`? I am lack of experience .

Comment: Because vim searches these paths and not the subfolders for those folders.

Comment: Instead of `vim`, if your system has `nano`, TeX syntax highlighting might be built-in. Only syntax highlighting.